# How to generally use PrimeIcons of PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I'm a bit confused to not find anything here, how to use PrimeIcons of PrimeFaces. I just wanted to use the icon of an PrimeFaces example:

```
 <p:contextMenu for="table">
     <p:menuitem value="Löschen" update="table" icon="pi pi-times" action="#{telefonbuchList.deleteEntry}"/>
 </p:contextMenu>
```

The "pi pi-times". Instead I just get a ^. I don't even want to use FontAwesome and this stuff right now. I thought the icons are already implemented with the dependency of PrimeFaces, but I seem to be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First... you must be using PF 6.2.11 or 7.0 or higher: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4228

Second you add this to your XHTML:

```xml
<h:outputStylesheet name="primeicons/primeicons.css" library="primefaces"/>
```

**Update 03/16/2021**: Starting with PrimeFaces 10.0.0 PrimeIcons is automatically added to all pages.

Comment: Agreed, this stuff we should not have to look up on stack overflow.

Comment: Am I right that the newest version of PrimeFaces on Maven is 6.2 and I need to import the jar manually?

Comment: Its not available in public 6.2 Release only in Elite 6.2.11 or higher.  It will be included in public PF 7.0 in the new few weeks.

Comment: I have updated the documentation to reflect this: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/fonticons